# This referring to clicked object and not to namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, scope

Let's say I have a `namespace` and several `function`s , e.g. in this way :

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="click">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var nms = {
 doAlert: function(){
     alert('doing alert');
     console.log(this);
 },
 bindBtn: function(){
     var that = this;
     $('.btn').on('click', that.doAlert);
 }

}

nms.bindBtn();
```

the `log` prints  `<input type="button" class="btn" value="click">` ,in  other words, `this` refers to the element I'm executing the `function` in.

It is probably my lack, but I would like to understand how can I refer to `nms` instead of `input`. If possible, using `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. I prefer to define the object inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (immediately invoked function expression) so that it can use a private variable to keep track of itself:

```
var nms = (function () {
    var myownself = {
        doAlert: function () {
            alert('doing alert');
            console.log(myownself);
        },
        bindBtn: function () {
            $('.btn').on('click', myownself.doAlert);
        }
    };
    return myownself;
})();

nms.bindBtn();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yu5Mx/

That way, all of the methods of that object can just refer to the `myownself` variable but they don't need to know about the `nms` variable by which the object is known to the rest of your code. And if you do something like:

```
var temp = nms.bindBtn;
temp();
```

...which "messes up" the value of `this` within `bindBtn()` then it doesn't matter, because `bindBtn()` will still use `myownself`.

Note that this pattern assumes that `nms` will be a singleton object. If you want to be able to instantiate multiple copies you can still use the same general idea, but use a factory function or a conventional constructor function with `new` (rather than an IIFE).

Comment: This is a good solution. Otherwise, what if I have 3 different module and I have to call one module's function in an another function, does IIFE guarantee tis possibility?

Comment: If the `nms` variable is in scope from your other modules they can just say `nms.bindBtn()` or `nms.doAlert()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) jquery's method to apply specific context:

```
$('.btn').on('click', $.proxy( this.doAlert, this ));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GgfNR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nms = {
 doAlert: function(){
     alert('doing alert');
     console.log(this);
 },
 bindBtn: function(){
     $('.btn').on('click', nms.doAlert.bind(nms));
 }
}
```

To support bind for IE you can [use this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)

Comment: If you're going to assume that the `bindBtn()` function knows about the `nms` variable then why not assume that `doAlert()` does too?

Comment: @nnnnnn You could use `var me = this;` and then `me.doAlert.bind(me);` but the main thing is that jQuery sets `this` to the Element that triggered the event and you can bypass that with bind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var nms = {
 doAlert: function(){
     alert('doing alert');
     console.log(this);
 },
 bindBtn: function(){
     var that = this;
     $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        nms.doAlert.apply(that);

     });
 }

}

nms.bindBtn();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmvYq/1/)

This passes `that` through the function as `this`

You can use `call()` for this too

Some links

[apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
[call();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Or Without using call or apply

```
var nms = {
 doAlert: function(){
     var _this = nms;
     alert('doing alert');
     console.log(_this);
 },
 bindBtn: function(){
     var that = this;
     $('.btn').on('click', nms.doAlert);
 }

}

nms.bindBtn();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmvYq/)

Comment: If you're going to assume that the `bindBtn()` function knows about the `nms` variable then why not assume that `doAlert()` does too?